# Unmano Sliding Panel Layout Set Maximum Sliding Height

Tags: android

I'm using sliding panel layout by unmano but i want the sliding panel to slide up to a certain height no more

here's my xml

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="120dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" /></RelativeLayout>
```

tried changing layout_height but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting sothree:umanoParallaxOffset